# nodejs searchkit demos "Cannot find module 'react'."

Tags: node.js, reactjs, searchkit

I'm trying to install a searchkit demo "IMDB Search Demo": http://searchkit.co/demos

I copied the contents of: https://github.com/searchkit/searchkit-demo to a folder on my Desktop

I installed nodejs, went into that folder in cmd, typed "npm install" and "npm start"

There is a ridiculously large list of errors that say for example:

```
ERROR in ./src/index.tsx
(2,24): error TS2307: Cannot find module 'react'.
```

and at the end:

```
webpack: Failed to compile
```

I then used "npm i -S react" to install react myself.

npm start: same error messages.

At localhost:3000 there opens a webpage that says "Sample App" in the header, but the page is blank white.

Do you have any Idea why this does not work? I tried it on ubuntu: same result, so i guess I'm missing something important.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may have forgotten to install [`tsd`](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/tsd) package manager and run `tsd install` as stated in [searchkit-demo project](https://github.com/searchkit/searchkit-demo) :

```
npm install tsd -g
```

Then install with `tsd` and `npm` (react is installed with `tsd`) :

```
tsd install
npm install
```

Then with `npm start` :

```
webpack built e4e4b2ce528a415bed3e in 5340ms
Version: webpack 1.14.0
Time: 5340ms
    Asset     Size  Chunks             Chunk Names
bundle.js  2.79 MB       0  [emitted]  main
webpack: Compiled successfully.
```

Comment: yes, that is correct. Pretty obvious. I have even noticed that there is this readme before, but idk why I didn't do what was told there. Maybe it's because I'm sick at the moment and my mind was not clear. Unfortunately this was kinda urgent. Thank you.